# Yahoo Video Upload with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I want to use cURL to post a video to Yahoo Video. I planned to make two calls to yahoo as follows:

1. call to sign in to an existing account and store the returned cookie
2. call to send the cookie, collected video metadata (title, description, etc.), AND the file

But the problem is that apparently, the original Video Upload form sends the data in two calls. The obvious one is a POST which only sends the meta data. The file itself is handled by a flash uploader and it is not clear where the data is sent and what is sent along with the file data itself.

Any idea where to look for answers?

Answer (score 0):

It'll be interesting to see who responds to this, as there is no API that allows you to upload to Yahoo Video.  See: http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html#apis

If there's no API, you cannot do this no matter how much you'd like. When companies have proprietary technology for uploading content, it's typically for a reason, so that people cannot post content without them knowing where it originated (and thus making them incapable of tracking inappropriate use).

Comment: I checked the developer resource before posting here. True there is no API. But, there ARE proxy services helping content distributors upload to a single point and syndicate to many sites. OneLoad (tm) from Tube Mogul is one. If the absence of API was for the reason you mentioned, the companies would take steps to stop such services. And the very existence of such services proves that even without an API you can do this if you are determined.

Comment: TubeMogul typically builds partnerships and thus can gain access to internal APIs along with permission to use them, often in exchange for some form of revenue sharing.  You can always contact them and ask how they do it.